May I get in ? Is it archaic?
The grammar book suggests that, "May is used in a formal context like between teachers/authority figures and students." This grammar book was published by Oxford Printing Press in 2014.
But a comment in ELL : People stopped using "may" for permission since the 1950s.
My question:
Has "may" been totally replaced by "can" for requesting permission to enter?.
Please find below the use of modal verbs -  may and can..
Ref. Adventures with Grammar and Composition, Beena Sugatham. Oxford Printing Press.

Permissions-can, could, may:.
We use can, may and could to ask for and give permissions. The choice of modal depends on the context and the relationship between the speaker and the listener. May is used in a formal context like between teachers/authority figures and students. Can is used between friends in an informal context. Could is a polite way of asking for permission. For example:
1.ANIL: My pen is not working. Can I use yours, Nitin?
NITIN: Yes, you can.
.
2.ANIL: May I submit my work, ma'am?
TEACHER: Yes, you may, Anil.
.
3.NITIN: Ma'am, could I bring it tomorrow?
TEACHER: Yes, you may.


Prescriptivism.

Is this a real dialogue that you heard at your school?

@JamesK I have edited my post and included a topic on use of may and can. Such examples are commonly used to show the difference between the two modal verbs.

Thanks, but that's not the question.  Is the original dialogue quoted from real life, or quoted from a book, or something that you said?

@JamesK I have answered that. The teacher's words are commonly used for teaching "can" and "may".. It is as popular as "Make hay while the sun shines."

So you didn't actually hear anyone say "You can, but you may not". But you feel it is a well known saying.  I suppose that is right and there is already a question answered about it.

"Can I come in?" is more idiomatic to my ears. Actually, in this case "May I come in?“ sounds better to me. Can I get in? sounds a little unusual. Get in where? A car?

The duplicate has "Can I sit here?" it is asking for permission, but some persnickety people insist that "can" is used for ability and "may"for permission. How does the top answer in the older question not answer your own question?

@Mari-LouA There is Michael Harvey's comment which correctly explains the explanation in the grammar book. May be this grammar is lost. When I was a kid in a London local-authority infants school (age 5-7), in the 1950s, the teachers used to say "You can, but you may not" and wait for the child to rephrase the question. –
Michael Harvey

So... the older question does provide the answer(s) for this question? Essentially, the grammar is old fashioned but you ask what is the difference between the two modal verbs. So why is your question different? Because the dialogue is between a teacher and a student? I don't think I will vote to reopen this question.

@Mari-LouA The point is not about reopening the question. It is not old fashioned.. In a conversation with a guard is okay but not with a teacher or a parent or a boss. I don't know if it is being followed. According to Cambridge dictionary - Asking for permission
Can I ask you a question? = informal
Could I use your phone ? = more formal/polite
May I use your phone = even more formal/polite.
Giving permission
Yes, you can.= informal
Yes, you may.= formal/polite

I give up. In the edit which you made when the question was closed you said The post in ELL doesn't address the difference appropriately. So, you don't mind it being closed as a duplicate. OK P.S In the UK this type of distinction used to exist, but no longer. If a child asks a teacher "Can I go to the bathroom?" The teacher  will not correct him/her.

@Mari-LouA The grammar book by Oxford University Press was printed in 2014 and is still being used.

Which grammar book? Which unit? And who is the author? Practical English Usage, printed by Oxford University Press has been reprinted several times, it  was written by Michael Swan and was first published in 1980 (44 years ago) and probably took a few years to write.  In it Swan says (131) “Can, could, may and might are all used in asking for permission. Can is probably the commonest of the four (though some people consider that can is ‘not correct’ and that one should say May I …?" The "You can, but you may not" refers to this distinction. Not if it is formal or informal.

In the past there was a widespread perception, particularly among pedantic English teachers, that “may” is the more polite form to use in this scenario. There are still some who hold strong on this view today, and in formal settings you’ll hear “may” frequently. I believe this is because there is still a subjective belief that it is more polite, but also because it is genuinely a more precise word choice than “can” in these cases.

You'll hear "may" frequently in informal settings too, although more in some circles and age groups than others.

You'll hear requests "May I ...?“ more commonly among American English speakers

The grammar book (for Indian students) which explains the usage is printed by Oxford University Press was printed in 2014 and is still being used.
According to Cambridge dictionary - Asking for permission Can I ask you a question? = informal Could I use your phone ? = more formal/polite May I use your phone = even more formal/polite. Giving permission Yes, you can.= informal Yes, you may.= formal/polite

I think the teacher was just being humorous, especially if she was an English teacher and was attempting to test the student on the two meanings of can as defined by Google:


be able to; 2. be permitted to


Obviously,  the student was using sense 2 (there's nothing difficult in walking into the office), and hence there's no difference between that and may.

Some teachers insist that students should say, "May I come in ?"

Yes, I think so too.  This is prescriptivism as what Andy rightly said.
